# onOptionsItemSelected is not called for activity which intent another activity class

Tags: java, android, android-intent, view, android-activity

I want to use a library activity with my test app onOptionsItemSeleceted method() but I figure out that if I use intent. Android use library activity's onOptionsItemSeleceted method() not my test activity method(). I did one test app and my MainActivity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Test_1.class);
    startActivity(intent);



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_setting:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        case R.id.action_setting1:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And my test activity class is like:

```
public class Test_1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_1);

    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    txt.setText("This is new page");

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_1, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return false;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I want to use onOptionsItemSelected() method in Main Activity class but I couldn't see my Toast messages on the screen.
I really appreciated if you can help me. Thanks :)

Comment: Try to extend MainActivity in  Test_1

Comment: @A.S. I already tried that one. In that case, intent is not working.

Comment: I assume the menu in main is a subset of the menu in test_1 in which case you can make it a subclass of the Test_1.I guess you can extend MainActivity in Test_1 and have a default in switch case which calls super.onOptionsItemSelected.Did you register your Test_1 in the manifest?

Comment: @user2309862 Yes,I registered Test_1 in the manifest. When I extend MainActivity, intent doesn't work. super.onOptionsItemSelected cannot go back to MainActivity for menu.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Maybe it go through ?

```
default:
      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

I'm not sure what is in R.menu.main
But make sure there are R.id.action_setting, R.id.action_setting1, R.id.action_settings.

Comment: I check so many times every declaration is okey. Problem is after intent I cannot use MainActivity onOptionsItemSelected method.

Comment: OK, i got that, because of you go to another intent.
Main -> Test1

Comment: So your methond in MainActivity would not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

SUPER:

It is used inside a sub-class method definition to call a method defined in the super class. 
In your case `Activity` is a super class of `Test_1` onOptionsItemSelected of activity will  be called .. not the `MainActivity` onOptionsItemSelected

Just add this to see your toast messages. In class Test_1 onOptionsItemSelected :

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_setting:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    case R.id.action_setting1:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Button is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```